# The argument type 'AnimationController?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animation<double>'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I am new to Flutter.

So I am trying to use Curved animations in flutter but it gives me a type error as mentioned in the title. I have shared my main.dart and welcome_screen.dart below. In [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial) https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial they have also used the Animationcontroller and a curve (along with Tween) and I think I have done the same. How to solve this?

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import 'package:flash_chat/screens/welcome_screen.dart'; import 'package:flash_chat/screens/login_screen.dart'; import 'package:flash_chat/screens/registration_screen.dart'; import 'package:flash_chat/screens/chat_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(FlashChat());

class FlashChat extends StatelessWidget {   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        textTheme: TextTheme(bodyText1: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54)),
      ),
      initialRoute: WelcomeScreen.id,
      routes: {
        WelcomeScreen.id: (context) => WelcomeScreen(),
        LoginScreen.id: (context) => LoginScreen(),
        RegistrationScreen.id: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
        ChatScreen.id: (context) => ChatScreen(),
      },
    );   } }
```

welcome_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import 'package:flash_chat/screens/login_screen.dart'; import 'package:flash_chat/screens/registration_screen.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {   static const String id
= 'welcome_screen';

  @override   _WelcomeScreenState createState() =>
_WelcomeScreenState(); }

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {   AnimationController? controller;   Animation? animation;

  @override   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      upperBound: 100,
    );
    animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.decelerate);
    controller!.forward();

    controller!.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
      print(controller!.value);
    });   }

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Hero(
                  tag: 'logo',
                  child: Container(
                    child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
                    height: controller!.value,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Flash Chat',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 45.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey.shade300,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 48,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
              child: Material(
                elevation: 5.0,
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                child: TextButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    foregroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
                  },
                  child: Text('Login'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
              child: Material(
                elevation: 5.0,
                color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                child: TextButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    foregroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, RegistrationScreen.id);
                  },
                  child: Text('Register'),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );   } }
```

My full error is below

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Lenovo TB 7504X...
lib/screens/welcome_screen.dart:25:41: Error: The argument type 'AnimationController?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animation<double>' because 'AnimationController?' is nullable and 'Animation<double>' isn't.
 - 'AnimationController' is from 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter_windows_2.5.1-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/animation_controller.dart').
 - 'Animation' is from 'package:flutter/src/animation/animation.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter_windows_2.5.1-stable/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/animation.dart').
    animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.decelerate);
                                        ^
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `controller!` here `CurvedAnimation(parent: controller!...` like bellow:

```
 @override   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      upperBound: 100,
    );
    animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller!, curve: Curves.decelerate);
    controller!.forward();

    controller!.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
      print(controller!.value);
    });   }
```

`AnimationController` can be assigned to `Animation<Double>` since `AnimationController extends Animation<double>` the only problem is of **null safety**. In the tutorial they have initialized `AnimationController` with **late** keyword but since you have used `AnimationController?` you need to make it null safe.

Comment: nice one @Krish Bhanushali

Answer (score 1):

AnimationController used with late keyword In the tutorial they have initialized so using late keyword you do'nt need to make null safe every where and initstate it will initialize compulasary because of using late keyword.

```
late AnimationController controller; 
  Animation? animation;

@override   void initState() {
  super.initState();
  controller = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    upperBound: 100,
  );
  animation = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.decelerate);
  controller.forward();

  controller.addListener(() {
    setState(() {});
    print(controller.value);
  });   }
```

Comment: I somehow missed that. Thanks a lot!!!!